# django export to csv only exports data from current page

Tags: django, csv, listview, export

I am trying to export a django Listview to csv. I created a view for a ListView, which has a custom get_queryset() function to create the filtered result. The Listview itself uses pagination for displaying the data.

For the export i created a subclass, inheriting the Listview, with a custom url and a csv template file.

The Listview and the export process itself works pretty fine, but i do not get the complete queryset in the csv, but only the data present on the first page of the paginated Listview.

Any suggestions what i am missing?

Comment: could you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you make a base abstract View, one that doesn't get put in the urlpatterns, that has the common logic:

```py
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = Foo

    def get_queryset(...):
        ...
```

Then have one for your CSV with any different functionality:

```py
class MyCSVListView(MyListView):
    ...
```

And one for your regular view:

```py
class MyPaginatedListView(MyListView):
    paginate_by = 100
```

This way, you should avoid any side-effects from the other view.

Comment: Ok, changed to the suggested design. Now i have a kind of opposite problem, means the complete queryset gets exported. As i have filters and limits from url parameters applied in the get_queryset function of the base view. The paginated view in the browser does everything correct using the returned object_list from the get_queryset funtion. But,these filters and limits seem to get lost when exporting to csv